# Sfgrid column headers don't line up with the columns

Tags: syncfusion, mdc

[image: Screenshot]

I tried AutoFit="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" and messing with the widths.  I'm having difficulty getting the headers to line up with the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved by setting HeaderTextAlignment as a start on manually generated columns. For more details please refer to the below UG link.

UG link : https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/column-types#headertextalignment

Regards,
Karthik Raja